# CSS Centre Column - Clearing Error?

Tags: css

I'm very new to CSS and have been sitting here for hours trying to figure out why my middle section is not displaying as a column.  I've searched the net with apparently no success.  I have tried repositioning the divs, clearing everything and floating the bejesus out of everything.  It must be something simple, but I don't know what.  Could anyone help?

I apologize for the large amount of code if that isn't appropriate, but I don't yet have anything uploaded.

Thanks in advance

HTML

```
<head><style type="text/css" media="all">@import "css/master.css";</style></head>

<body>
<div id="page-container">
    <!-- RIGHT HAND PAGE -->
    <div id="navbar">NavBar</div>
    <div id="mediaplayer">Meda Player</div>
    <div id="sightings">Sightings</div>
    <div id="blogheader">Blog Header</div>
    <div id="sociallinks">Social Links</div>
    <!-- LEFT HAND PAGE -->
    <div id="logo">Logo</div>
    <div id="mainpic">MainPic</div>
    <!-- CENTRE PAGE -->
    <div id="headline">Headline</div>
    <div id="newsitems">News Items</div>
    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#page-container {
width:960px;
margin:auto;
background:red;
}

html, body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#logo {
background:purple;
height:150px;
width:270px;
margin-right:450px;
}

#mainpic {
background:darkgrey;
width:270px;
height:450px;
}

#navbar {
float:right;
background:lightblue;
height:50px;
width:690px;
}

#headline {
background:grey;
height:200px;
margin-left:270px;
margin-right:350px;
}

/* News Items Mock - height:350px */ 
#newsitems {
background:blue;
margin-left:270px;
margin-right:350px;
}

#mediaplayer {
clear:both;
float:right;
background:black;
height:200px;
width:350px;
}

/* Sightings Mock - height:150px; */
#sightings {
clear:both;
float:right;
background:green;
width:350px;
}

#blogheader {
clear:both;
float:right;
background:darkgreen;
height:40px;
width:350px;
}

#sociallinks {
clear:both;
float:right;
background:orange;
height:40px;
width:350px;
}

#footer {
background:yellow;
clear:both;
height:30px;
}
```

Comment: I can't make up the design you're going for, can you post a mockup or a better explanation of what it is that you are expecting?

Comment: Sorry about that - I edited my post to show a link to the image as my rep means I can't post it just yet.

Comment: please make a mockup of your result what exactly do you need because we will see it what are you looking & how did u make the code of your mockup so that would be easier for us to find out the error in your code & will try to get solution....

Comment: My mockup is in the image above.  Is that not appropriate?  I don't know what you mean by how did I make the code?  If it helps I coded in Aptana Studio3.  I have already said what I needed - my centre column appears to clear everything and I don't know why.

Comment: @user1289829 don't know if my eyes are failing me but your code renders the same design as in your mockup, here is a fiddle of your code. [View here](http://jsfiddle.net/wSejZ/show/), edit [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wSejZ/).

Comment: Yes exactly.  That's the problem.  I've done something wrong because those two middle boxes (grey and blue) should be a third centre column.  I don't see that I've done anything to cause them to clear below everything else?

Comment: @user1289829 wait, you posted a mockup of your error? i thought that was the design you were going for :P Can you post another mockup of the design you actually want? I still don't understand the design you're going for.

Comment: BTW thanks for the jsfiddle link - this isn't something I knew about before!  I will use that from now on.

Comment: Well no need for a mockup as it's very simple - that is the design I want, apart from the two boxes marked 'Headline' and 'News Items'.  They should be hard to the top alongside the left and right hand boxes as a central column.  They are in the right place with the right width etc, just their positioning is incorrect - they should essentially be occupying all the red space above.

Comment: +1 for 'floating the bejesus out of it.'

Comment: lol Well I did!  Still though, I'm sure this is something really simple but because I'm a beginner I'm having trouble debugging what I've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem i see is that you're trying to stack a series of divs one in top of the other without any containers to create a three-column page design, while that might be done with css it would be simpler to create a series of containers for each column that you can use to stack your divs under. Take this for example:

If you created a series of column divs you can easily stack all of your page sections inside of its own column, this way you can easily stack as many sections as you want in your page without having to comeback to your css and positioning it the way you're doing it now.

```
<div class="column">
   <section>
   <section>
</div>

<div class="column">
   <section>
   <section>
</div>

<div class="column">
   <section>
   <section>
</div>
```

Once you have your columns declared in your markup, you can then float them so they stack next to each other and then you can use a clearfix so they won't go under one another, like so:

```
.column:before, .column:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

.column:after {
    clear:both;
}

.column {
    zoom:1; /* ie hasLayout fix */
    float:left;
}
```

Here is a demo of your code with the columns implemented with the results i think you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/wSejZ/1/show/, you can edit the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wSejZ/1/.

Notice how the sections are stacked inside of a column, this way you can stack as many sections as you want and they will be stacked appropriately inside their container.

Comment: That's it - fantastic!  I should have figured to create separate containers at first.  I don't understand some of that CSS, however, I can read up on it.  Thanks for all your perseverance with me!

Comment: @tomdot i used this clearfix technique on the columns by the way, http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/, so you can read up on the "why" it is used.